# How to deploy a [Ruby on Rails] site in a scalable way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scalability, linode

I have been working on my [first] startup for a month now, and while it's probably atleast one more month away from an alpha release, I want to know how to deploy it the right way. The site will have an initial high amount of load (network + CPU) for a new user, so I am thinking of having a separate server/queue for this initial process, so that it doesn't slow down the site for existing users.

Based on my research so far, I am currently leaning towards nginx + haproxy + unicorn/thin + memcached + mysql, and deploying on Linode. However, I have no prior experience in any of the above; hence I am hoping to tap the community's experience.

- Does the above architecture seem reasonable? Any suggestions/articles/books that you would recommend?
- Is Linode a good choice? Heroku/EY seem too expensive for me (atleast until I have enough revenue), but am I missing some other better option? MediaTemple?
- Any good suggestions on the load balancing architecture? I am still reading up on this.
- Is it better have 2 separate Rails server instances on 2 separate linodes, or running 1 instance on a linode of twice capacity (in terms of RAM/storage/bandwidth)? How many Linodes should I start with?
- Which Linux distribution should I choose? (Linode offers 8 different ones - http://www.linode.com/faq.cfm) Are there any relative advantages/disadvantages between them for a Rails site?

I apologize if any of my questions are stupid or contradictory; please attribute it to my inexperience.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Architecture**

You're on the right track. I personally prefer Passenger over thin/unicorn (having run nginx to thin backends for a long while) just for the convenience, but your proposed setup is fairly standard. If you're on Ruby 1.8.7, I'd recommend that you consider REE + Passenger for framework memory savings, though.

**Hosting & Load Balancing**

Linode is fantastic, and I use them for just about everything I can, but you will need to be aware of RAM limits. Each Rails processes uses a nontrivial amount of RAM, and you'll want to avoid getting the machine into swap. Plan on running enough Rails instances per machine so that your memory allocation is about 90% of the memory on the Linode. You'll likely want another Linode dedicated to your database, though you can start with them both on the same machine; just be prepared to split off MySQL as you grow. You can set up communications between Linodes in the same data center on private IPs, which don't count against your bandwidth quota.

Your scaling strategy should be as horizontal as possible, so I'd recommend just getting a second Linode and adding it to your haproxy pool when you need more horsepower - Linode charges you $20 for 512mb more RAM, or you can just get a whole 'nother Linode (with CPU, RAM, HDD, and bandwidth quota) for that same $20. Seems a no-brainer!). In Rails' case, an instance is an instance is an instance, so it really doesn't matter if it's on the same VM or not, as long as the time to connect to your database machine or whatnot are more or less the same. You could be running 10 Linodes each running 10 Rails processes apiece without much of an issue. Linode also offers IP failover, so that if your primary Linode (with haproxy) goes down, it can fail over automatically to a secondary Linode, which you would then have haproxy running on, and ready to act in the same capacity as the first.

**Distribution**

Honestly, this is up to you! Many folks go with Ubuntu or Redhat (CentOS/Fedora) distros - I like CentOS myself - but it's really just about what you feel most comfortable with. If you don't have a favorite distro, I would recommend trying Ubuntu/CentOS, as they tend to be quite friendly to the beginner, and have extremely robust community support.

You will probably want to pick a 32-bit distro unless you have a compelling reason to pick a 64-bit distro; 64-bit executables require more RAM than their 32-bit counterparts, and since RAM is likely to be your most precious resource, it makes sense to save it where you can.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply.
A few followup questions for you :-

(1) I am using Ruby 1.9.2. Does REE still have an advantage in that case?
(2) What advantage does Passenger provide over Thin?

Comment: Passenger automatically manages your process cluster. With thin, you have to manage each backend manually. Passenger also takes advantage of REE's copy-on-write functionality to share framework memory across backend instances, saving you RAM. It's pretty dead-simple to install and configure, too.